# Allow only ascii characters VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to take some text from powerpoint to use in other software. But this software only supports ASCII characters (no extended ASCII). How can I make to remove the the character that are not ASCII? Is there any method to make that in VBA?

Comment: You'll have to iterate over the text/characters and check for a `Chr` value that is out of bounds for your character set.  If you have specific problems implementing this, please post what code you have tried so far, and where it's failing.

Comment: possibly you could use some RegEx... plenty of examples you will find here, in SO site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our Access VBA code, we use 2 functiions to convert Extended Latin to ASCII, hope that will work for VBA Power Point:

I. chrRemoveAccents() removes accent from a character,

II. strRemoveAccents() removes accents from a string, using chrRemoveAccents().

```
Function chrRemoveAccents(ByVal c1)
  Dim iCode As Long
  iCode = AscW(c1)
'
  Select Case iCode
'
' À = 192; Á = 193; Â = 194; Ã = 195; Ä = 196; Å = 197;
'
    Case 192 To 197
      chrRemoveAccents = "A"
'
' Æ = 198;
'
    Case 198
      chrRemoveAccents = "AE"
'
' Ç = 199;
'
    Case 199
      chrRemoveAccents = "C"
'
' È = 200; É = 201; Ê = 202; Ë = 203;
'
    Case 200 To 203
      chrRemoveAccents = "E"
'
' Ì = 204; Í = 205; Î = 206; Ï = 207;
'
    Case 204 To 207
      chrRemoveAccents = "I"
'
' Ð = 208;
'
    Case 208
      chrRemoveAccents = "D"
'
' Ñ = 209;
'
    Case 209
      chrRemoveAccents = "N"
'
' Ò = 210; Ó = 211; Ô = 212; Õ = 213; Ö = 214; Ø = 216;
'
    Case 210 To 216
      chrRemoveAccents = "O"
'
' Ù = 217; Ú = 218; Û = 219; Ü = 220;
'
    Case 217 To 220
      chrRemoveAccents = "U"
'
' Ý = 221; Ÿ = 376;
'
    Case 221, 376
      chrRemoveAccents = "Y"
'
' Œ = 338;
'
    Case 338
      chrRemoveAccents = "OE"
'
' Š = 352;
'
    Case 352
      chrRemoveAccents = "S"
'
'
' à=224, á = 225; â = 226; ã = 227; ä = 228; å = 229;
'
    Case 224 To 229
      chrRemoveAccents = "a"
'
' æ = 230;
'
    Case 230
      chrRemoveAccents = "ae"
'
' ç = 231;
'
    Case 231
      chrRemoveAccents = "c"
'
' è = 232; é = 233; ê = 234; ë = 235;
'
    Case 232 To 235
      chrRemoveAccents = "e"
'
' ì = 236; í = 237; î = 238; ï = 239;
'
    Case 236 To 239
      chrRemoveAccents = "i"
'
' ð = 240;
'
    Case 240
      chrRemoveAccents = "d"
'
' ñ = 241;
'
    Case 241
      chrRemoveAccents = "n"
'
' ò = 242; ó = 243; ô = 244; õ = 245; ö = 246;
'
    Case 242 To 246
      chrRemoveAccents = "o"
'
' ù = 249; ú = 250; û = 251; ü = 252;
'
    Case 249 To 252
      chrRemoveAccents = "u"
'
' ý = 253; ÿ = 255;
'
    Case 253, 255
      chrRemoveAccents = "y"
'
' œ = 339;
'
    Case 339
      chrRemoveAccents = "oe"
'
' š = 353;
'
    Case 353
      chrRemoveAccents = "s"
'
    Case Else
      chrRemoveAccents = c1
  End Select
End Function

Function strRemoveAccents(ByVal varIn)
  Dim i As Long, lng As Long
'
  Dim str1 As String
  str1 = ""
'
  If (Not IsNull(varIn)) Then
'
    lng = Len(varIn)
'
    For i = 1 To lng
      str1 = str1 & chrRemoveAccents(Mid(varIn, i, 1))
    Next
'
  End If
'
  strRemoveAccents = str1
End Function
```

Call:

```
strAscii = strRemoveAccents("écolière")
```

Gives:

```
strAscii = "ecoliere"
```